# Is "Amen" originally Arabic word?

Tags: arabic

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

It seems to me that "Amen" is originally not Arabic word. Meybe it was adopted into Arabic from Hebrew?

So the question is, **Is "Amen" originally Arabic word?**

Or, **was "Amen" originally Arabic word at the time of the Prophet Muhammad SAW?**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amen) says it is originally Hebrew word. I hope experts of Arabic language will respond to my inquiry.

Comment: Is your question about the word "alamin"?

Comment: No. It is about "Amen" or "Amin", uttered after Al-Fatiha. Or at the end of prayer.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfortunately not an expert in Arabic but I have found the following note in my Hebrew and Aramaic dictionary that also mentions the usage of the same roots in Arabic and Geez words.

> **אמן** (alef mem nun) Amen or amin, also Aramaic and Ancient Southern
> Arabic **امن** (alif mim nun): *firm, solid*.

So, this word already existed in Arabic before the time of the Prophet Muhammad (p.b.u.h.).

The usage of the word as an affirmation behind the prayer has most probably been introduced by Christians and Jews who settled in Arabia or Arabs who converted to Christianity before Muhammad (p.b.u.h.). So,

- it is an originally Arabic word
- the use after the prayer goes back to a Judeo-Christian tradition
- it was used in this sense before Muhammad (p.b.u.h.)

Comment: Aramaic came before Hebrew which came before Arabic

Comment: You cannot really say which language is older; they all developed from the same root and gradually developed locally. But they were the three distinct reference languages known in the Arabia in the time of Muhammad (p.b.u.h)

Comment: Then you should write it is originally an aramaic word and not arabic

Answer (score -2):

The original Word "Amen" was used by the Israelite in Egypt to mimic "Amon", the official god, to avoid punishment by Pharaoh's soldiers since they were known to worship the ONE God known as "Aten".
It means "Please Answer", like "Roger" used in the Walki-Talki communication.
For Moslems, however, they can avoid saying it, or if they say it (after Fateha), they should wait, in silence, to allow their inner selves to digest the received "Answer". (وَقَالَ رَبُّكُمُ ٱدْعُونِىٓ أَسْتَجِبْ لَكُمْ ۚ).